# Bad input warning on python

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
i = 1
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    if i==1 :
        largest = num
        smallest = num
        i=i+1
    elif i>=2 :
            try:
                int(num)
                if num > largest:
                    largest = num
                elif num < smallest:
                    smallest = num
            except(ValueError): 
                print  "Invalid input"   

print "Maximum", largest
print "Minimum", smallest
```

I got bad input on the line 13 when I am doing homework, but I can run on my editor ... and I can get the output what I want

So what is the problem here ?

thanks

Comment: please post your code, input and output here.  these questions live on, long after your codepad is gone.

Comment: What is this even supposed to do?

Comment: I didn't run your code, but `int(num)` by itself doesn't do anything. Did you intend to assign the result to a variable?

Comment: Note this code was returning messed up answers

Comment: I think it might be run error with the line int(num) , it should be num=(int)num

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what interpreter you are using, or if it even makes a difference, but to set num to an int you need to change `int(num)` to `num = int(num)`.

Note that

```
if num > largest:
    largest = num
elif num < smallest:
    smallest = num
```

needs to be

```
if int(num) > int(largest):
    largest = num
if int(num) < int(smallest):
    smallest = num
```

otherwise, comparing a string to a integer will always return false, and elif isn't necessary.

Comment: I change the line 13 into num=(int)num , and it works

thanks